# Internal Location in a building using GPS/Wifi routeres/ bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, wifi

I am trying to create an android app which gives me position (floor as well) of the device in a building. 
I know that GPS is not of much help indoors.
Can you please tell me show should i go abt it?

Comment: this is an extremly complex task, think again if you need that.

Comment: And be prepared that it works only at that location where you have either installed bluie toot beacons, or have run an WLAN access points analyis. It will not run in general buildings.

Answer (score 0):

- 1.If Google has scanned it, u can use the Location API. U can check IndoorMaps in GoogleMaps.
- 1. If not, u have to write it on ur own. U have to use the fingerprint system. Means scan the wifi signals, save them and do that again in specific distance. U will have an array of fingerprints. U need more than 3 Wifi pro fingerprints. So if u scanned the floor/room, than u have map. Whenever u receive signals/fingerprint, u have to compare with ur map.

Thats just basics. U need a good algorithm, and use of device sensors.